# The Correct Use of \ifdefempty

Tags: formatting

I have developed a routing to loop through a list of unknown data which has been generated externally. When I try to display it I get unpredictable results.  The unpredictability is becasue I am unfamiliar with the interworkings of Latex. There are three output statements at the bottom of the example. The first works correctly but output is not in a useful format. The second cause the results to always display the false results of the "empty" test. The third not only always gives a false answer but also display 26 variables set, where clearly only 3 set exist. I realize my approach could be call brute force but any help is getting the 3rd command to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass [letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\EasAccBookA {B221}
\newcommand\EasAccBookB {}
\newcommand\EasAccBookC {B223}
\newcommand\EasAccPageA {P321}
\newcommand\EasAccPageB {}
\newcommand\EasAccPageC {P323}
\newcommand\EasAccInstA {}
\newcommand\EasAccInstB {I122}
\newcommand\EasAccInstC {}
\newcommand\Instrument {Instrument}

\newcounter{eaa}
\setcounter{eaa}{0}
\newcommand\LPEA {A}
\newcommand\ErEA [1] {EasAccBook#1}
\newcommand\ErEB [1] {EasAccPage#1}
\newcommand\ErEC [1] {EasAccInst#1}
\newcommand\ebookea {\csname\ErEA\LPEA\endcsname}
\newcommand\ebookeb {\csname\ErEB\LPEA\endcsname}
\newcommand\ebookec {\csname\ErEC\LPEA\endcsname} 
\renewcommand\theeaa{\Alph{eaa}}
\renewcommand\LPEA {\theeaa}
\loop
\ifnum\value{eaa}<26
\stepcounter{eaa}%

\ebookea \ebookeb \ebookec 
%\ifdefempty {\ebookea} {\ebookec} {\ebookea \, \ebookeb} 
%\ifdefempty {\ebookea} {\ebookec} {Book \ebookea, Page  \ebookeb}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple: Since you're loading `etoolbox` you should use `\csuse` to call a macro of which you don't know whether it is defined. Also you can use the test `\ifcsundef` to check whether a command is defined and `\ifcsempty` to check whether it has content. The problem is that your checks do look whether `\ebookea` is empty which it is in no case as it is defined as `\csname\ErEA\LPEA\endcsname`. Your code should then be something like:

```
\documentclass [letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\EasAccBookA {B221}
\newcommand\EasAccBookB {}
\newcommand\EasAccBookC {B223}
\newcommand\EasAccPageA {P321}
\newcommand\EasAccPageB {}
\newcommand\EasAccPageC {P323}
\newcommand\EasAccInstA {}
\newcommand\EasAccInstB {I122}
\newcommand\EasAccInstC {}
\newcommand\Instrument {Instrument}

\newcounter{eaa}
\setcounter{eaa}{0}
\newcommand\LPEA {A}
\newcommand\ErEA [1] {EasAccBook#1}
\newcommand\ErEB [1] {EasAccPage#1}
\newcommand\ErEC [1] {EasAccInst#1}
\newcommand\ebookea {\csuse{\ErEA\LPEA}}
\newcommand\ebookeb {\csuse{\ErEB\LPEA}}
\newcommand\ebookec {\csuse{\ErEC\LPEA}} 
\renewcommand\theeaa{\Alph{eaa}}
\renewcommand\LPEA {\theeaa}
\loop
\ifnum\value{eaa}<26
\stepcounter{eaa}%

%\ebookea \ebookeb \ebookec 
%\ifcsundef{\ErEA\LPEA}{\ebookec}{Book \ebookea, Page \ebookeb}
%\ifdefempty {\ebookea} {\ebookec} {\ebookea \, \ebookeb} 
\ifcsundef{\ErEA\LPEA}
  {}% do nothing if undefined
  {\ifcsempty {\ErEA\LPEA} {\ebookec} {Book \ebookea, Page \ebookeb}}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaulHill if the answer helped you, you should at least upvote it (if not done already) and if it completely solved your issues accept it after you waited for a reasonable amount of time to see if there will be better answers which should be accepted.